# When I update database with migration, User can't login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I develop an ASP.Net MVC 5 project locally using Azure DB. My connection string points my Azure SQL database.   The project works properly both local and on Azure after publishing.

I also use ASP.Net Identity. I can register and login without any problem, but when I `update-database` after any migration (after defining new model class), I can not login with my existing password/email.

The only changes I have done are:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { 
            UserName = model.Email, 
            Email = model.Email, 
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };
        //...
    }
}
```

> I just added **FirstName** and **LastName** properties and **UserName = model.Email**

I double checked whether it tries to login with `UserName`, although the `Register` action uses the email field.  But everything seems proper.

When I register with new account, log out and log in again it works fine. Then I `update-database`, I can not login anymore with that user.

Is that a known problem or where am I making the BIG mistake?

EDIT:
Configuration.cs:

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "myproject.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(myproject.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
```

And I have Date_InitialCreate.cs in Migrations folder that creates Identity tables.
Should I delete it?

EDIT-2:
1. I have 3 migrations. InitialCreate.cs is the standart as you know.
2. NameLastNametoUSERS.cs

```
public partial class NameLastNametoUSERS : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "FirstName", c => c.String(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "LastName", c => c.String(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "LastName");
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "FirstName");
    }
}
```

3. postcatimg.cs

`public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Categories",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    CategoryPhoto = c.String(),
                    URLSlug = c.String(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);`

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Posts",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 250),
                    PostContent = c.String(nullable: false),
                    ShortContent = c.String(),
                    FeaturedPhoto = c.String(),
                    URLSlug = c.String(nullable: false),
                    DateAdded = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    DatePublished = c.DateTime(),
                    Published = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Category_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.Category_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Category_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Images",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ImgName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    ImgSize = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ImgFullPath = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Posts", "Category_Id", "dbo.Categories");
        DropIndex("dbo.Posts", new[] { "Category_Id" });
        DropTable("dbo.Images");
        DropTable("dbo.Posts");
        DropTable("dbo.Categories");
    }
```

`

Comment: What type of migration are you running?  Are you perchance using a migration initializer that drops and recreates the database?  Please post your EF `Configuration.cs` class.

Comment: Do you call `Database.SetInitializer()` anywhere in your code?  Your issues sounds like you are dropping and recreating the database during each migratation.

Comment: No I don't call 'Database.SetInitializer()' and also when I check the DB, I can see all the records for registered users who can not log in now. I think, something is changing Passwordhash. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok - so **new** users get registered with their email address as their username.  But **old** users were registered with something else other than email address as the username?  How many migrations do you have?  If only a couple, post the code for them as well.

Comment: If you seed all the users with a first/last name does that solve the problem? i.e. are you simply generating an exception on a read because nullable= false... but they're all null. Check you're not eating an exception that tells you exactly whats going on.

Comment: No need to seed because I register with UserName and FirstName filled. There is no user record in DB with null value of UserName and FirstName. What happens if I delete the InitialCreate.cs from the Migrations folder?